# android how to force stop an application on button click

Tags: android

I have an application where many activities are there.
I want in one activity's button click the application should be stopped( stopped in background).
How can i do that?
Thank you

Comment: Do you want to exit from the application or what ??

Comment: see this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: I didn't get you. can you please elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straight way

```
System.exit(1);
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to just call finish() and let the OS take care of killing off your process when/if it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

Application can not stopped in background through programming.if you want to exit application or want to finish all activities-

use this-

If you are calling activity B from an activity A.and C from B

A->B

use startactivityforresult from A

and again B->C

use startactivityforresult from B

and when you want to exit from C then setResult(i.e. RESULT_OK) and finish C.and in OnActivityResult() in B,check if resultcode == RESULT_OK then again finish B and setresult(RESULT_OK) for A.same procedure will follow to finish A.

this will exit you from the application.and application will start from A not from C.